# Difference between a vector vs a boost::optional<vector> as function parameter with default value set to empty vs boost::none?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, boost

What is the difference between having a function take a vector defaulted to be empty:

```
void foo (const vector<T> & vec = {})
```

versus one that takes a boost optional defaulted to boost::none

```
void bar (boost::optional<const vector<T>&> vec = boost::none)
```

in terms of runtime and memory efficiency?

Comment: You can't get away with using one over another, they simply mean different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `optional<vector>` has two empty states, compared to the one for `vector`: it can contain *no vector* or it can contain *a vector that is empty*. Setting aside the issue of efficiency for a moment, consider which type actually reflects your intent.

Usually `optional` will use slightly more memory since it needs an extra byte to indicate whether it contains an object or not. There is also a small cost to setting and checking that flag. However, this is not a reason to prefer one over the other, unless you have evidence that this causes a measurable difference in performance that is significant for your application.